# How to get dot product of 2 columns containing dense vectors in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, distributed-computing, word2vec, cosine-similarity

I have a spark data frame containing dense vectors as columns Col_W_DensV1 and Col_w_DenseV2 and now I want to calculate the cosine similarity between them and thus need dot product. I am currently using UDF and doing row operations and it is incredibly slow and uses just 1 core for operations. Can someone suggest a better way to achieve this?

#### My spark Dataframe

```sh
Col1  | Col2 | Col_W_DensV1   | Col_w_DenseV2  
a     | b    | [0.1 0.1 0.2..]| [0.3 0.5 0.8..]
```

Need `x.Dot(y)` at column level instead of row-level and parallelize

#### My Current function(Row-Level) Takes gazillion years to run on data!!

```
@udf("double")def cosim(x, y):
    import numpy as np
    return float(x.dot(y) / np.sqrt(x.dot(x)) /np.sqrt(y.dot(y)))
    cs_table1 = cs_table.withColumn("similarity",cosim(cs_table.p_result,cs_table.result))
    cs_table1.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a pandas udf for this:

```
def bulk_dot(
        iterator: Iterator[Tuple[pd.Series, pd.Series]]
    ) -> Iterator[pd.Series]:

    for input_series1, input_series2 in iterator:
        m1 = np.stack(input_series1)
        m2 = np.stack(input_series2)
        dots = np.einsum("ij, ij -> i", m1, m2)
        yield pd.Series(dots)

bulk_dot_udf = pandas_udf(bulk_dot, FloatType())
spark.udf.register("bulk_dot", bulk_dot_udf)
```